# How to exec multiple queries using mysqldb on flask

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python

I've been trying to make my code works but can't find why won't it does what it does.
I'm trying to put data in my database, by it only seem to exec one ....
The code is :

```
def setCubesValues(value):
    mysql.connection.autocommit(on=True)
    tabVal = value.split(';;')
    del tabVal[0]
    for i in range(0, len(tabVal)):
        tabi = tabVal[i]
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        responseCur = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM idcudetoaction where id_cube = "' + tabi +'"')
        if responseCur == 1:
            curResultInsert = cur.execute('update idcudetoaction set action = "' + tabi +'" where id_cube = ' + str(i))
        else:
            curResultInsert = cur.execute('insert into idcudetoaction (id_cube, action) values (' + str(i)+', "' + tabi +'")')
    return jsonify(curResultInsert);
```

Thing is I have 7 values, but only on that get put in the database ...

Any help ? :)
thx !

Comment: You sure they are separated by double semi-colon? Could you print `value` at the top of `setCubesValues`?

Comment: Yes it is :/
printing value returns ;;UN;;DEUX;;TROIS;;QUATRE;;CINQ

Comment: And `responseCur` above `if reponseCur == 1`? I presume you call `insert` once and `update` 6 times (with non-existing ID)... AFAIK `.execute` returns an iterator/object, not an integer...